# In Old English or in Middle English was "join" ever pronounced "jin?"

Tags: pronunciation

In Old English or in Middle English, was "join" ever pronounced "jin?"

Comment: Can you expand on the motivation for this question? Do you know of some reason to think that "join" was pronounced as "jin" at some point?

Comment: I don't know about Early or Middle English, but the village church near where I grew up (Derbyshire, UK) has an inscription (late 18th or early 19th century, I think) in which 'join' is supposed to rhyme with 'mine'.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, *join* and *jine* were pronounced very nearly, if not exactly, the same in the early 18th century (much more recently than Middle English), when Alexander Pope wrote:

> Good-Nature and Good-Sense must ever join;
>   To err is Humane; to Forgive, Divine.

Comment: This pronunciation is mentioned by the OED as  /dʒaɪn/.

Comment: @Laurel: but it wasn't /dʒaɪn/ when Pope wrote, even though is in dialects today. It was something like *join*. See the Wikipedia page for [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift). The vowel in *join* stayed more or less where it is today, while the vowel in *mine* moved past it; that webpage has /dʒʌɪn/, which is very close to /dʒɔɪn/. So for a few years, they were very close, if they didn't merge completely.

Comment: The OED pretty specifically calls this pronunciation out as being historical in addition to being used in some modern-day dialects: "The rhymes show the pronunciation /dʒaɪn/ in 17–18th cent.; this is still dialectal." In any case I'm not a fan of the Wikipedia article because it's super generalized and I find it hard to follow.

Answer (score -1):

No, "join" was not a part of the English vocabulary. The letter "J" was not invented by then. "Bindan" is Anglo-Saxon word for join. We still use this in Dutch(Binden).
Even in the original 1611 King James Bible there is no "J".
https://www.originalbibles.com/the-original-king-james-bible-1611-pdf/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. While it is correct that "j" was only used in the word from the 1600s onward, the word existed before then. In Middle English alone it had about 8 spellings, so it makes sense to discuss it using modern spelling to avoid confusion.

Comment: Out of curiosity - how did they spell the king's name in those days, without the "J"?

Comment: @Lawrence: see the link in this answer, scroll down to the listing of books.  Find such things as Ioshua, Iudges, Iob, etc.

Comment: @Lawrence: before the "J" came into widespread use, "I" served the purpose of both "I" and "J". So it was spelled "Iames" (but still pronounced *James*).

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, it was an interesting dive into the I/J history.

Comment: @PeterShor So it’s described. It sounds very plausible; I have no reason to challenge the claimed factual basis. Oddly, though, these days we see the letter ‘j’ pronounced in all sorts of ways, including without the characteristic ‘j’ sound, but we don’t find ‘i’ pronounced like ‘j’ in modern usage - I find the reversal puzzling. They could do without ‘j’ more convincingly than we can do without ‘i’.